# No IP address on VMware

Tags: vmware, ip-address

There is no IP address on VMware, so/and cannot connect to the internet. How to get the IP address?
Trying to understand what these technical things are. There is no NIC. Why it isn't showing NIC?

[image]

Comment: Network adapter is the same (different name). Your guest settings seem OK as is ("Bridged). If your host has multiple adapters/NICs you have to select the primary one to bridge to. You are looking for something like: http://www.serverwatch.com/imagesvr_ce/4846/vmnetcfg.png. However, automatic should have worked...

Comment: Another thing: How is you host connected? Is it Ethernet or wireless to a router?

Comment: It is Ethernet connection

Answer (score 2):

To configure networking have a look at [the manual](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_configure_ws.html) (although this is for Workstation the settings are very similar). If I remember, you first have to configure networking on the host. Usually there are 3 options:

- NATed network: Your host is working as a router for the guests and also handles DHCP/DNS. This allows for internet access and communication between the host and guests in that network. However, I am not sure if the guest will have access to the hosts in the real LAN
- Bridged: Your host is now working as a switch/bridge connecting the virtual network to your physical. In this setup the guest box will get an IP from the real network DHCP and it will belong in the real LAN.
- Host-Only: This is a virtual LAN where all the guests and the host are connected. However, this has no access to any other networks.

Most of the times, the above three options are configured in VMWare by default. What you have to do is to go to your guest "Network Settings" (or sth similar) and make it join/connect to one of these networks. You may also need to configure/add the guests NICs (Network Interface Cards) if not there. You will need at least one NIC

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

if you are using centos 8 make sure that the network interface is UP.

go to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
on network interface file put ONBOOT="yes"